# Tips to debug C in Visual Studio Code remotely using SSH and a Makefile?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-debugging

I have some C code and I need to debug this shared library. However the file is on a remote machine. I don't want to use gdb anymore, so I ssh into the remote machine within Visual studio. How do I then build using my makefile rule and debug while putting a break point into my shared library? Does anyone have good resources for me to look at?

Comment: Is the shared library on the remote system (and the remote system also runs the application using the library), but the project, code and editor is on your local system? Or do you edit, build and run all on the remote system?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's all on the remote system

Comment: Then I don't really see the problem. Log into the remote system, build as usual, and debug using `gdb` as usual. Running a shell locally or remotely over SSH is really the same thing. If you want to use windows and GUI's then use X forwarding to open up the editor and graphical debug environment on your local system (assuming it has an X server).